# Scrapy get callback data

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a webpage of ads. Thumbnails of ads are displayed on the first page that is paginated. Clicking on each thumbnail brings up the details of the particular ad which includes the posting date of the ad. Now I only want to scrape ads that have been posted during the last day.

My Scrapy spider has the following structure:

```
#opens the homepage
def start_requests(self):
        url = 'url_to_page'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

#parse the page for ad links and follow each of them
def parse(self, response):
    #get all links from current page; not shown here
    for link in ad_links:
        request = scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_single_ad)

    #follow the next page, only if today's date > posting date <---

def parse_single_ad(self, response):
    #get the posting date; not shown here
    return item
```

The problem is that I only have access to the posting date in `parse_single_ad()`, but I have to stop the pagination in `parse()` based on the ads' posting date. Is there any way to access the items retrieved in `parse_single_ad()` from `parse()`? More generally, can I access the callback's data from its parent function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CloseSpider` whenever you want to close your Spider manually.

You can do this in your `Spider` class or even in `Pipeline` if you want.

```
from scrapy import scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider

def parse(self, response):
     if some thing: # write your condition here
          raise CloseSpider('All ads scraped, now closing spider.')
     else:
          # Scrape next page
```

**EDIT:**

OP said that he does not have access to ad's posting date until ad details page is scraped.

But look this, you have date of ad posted in listing page.

[image]

Comment: would this only close the current branch of recursion? What if I have many urls to start with?

Comment: It will close execution of Spider ... If you have many `start_urls` then you will have issue ... because `CloseSpider` just QUITS spider.

Comment: What is website you are scraping? I have an idea, if you have some specific string in URL for each the URL in `start_urls` then we can ignore specific URLs from scraping in `process_request` method. Please share the website you are scraping, I will help you.

Comment: @Botond see my updated answer, you said you do not have access to ad's posting date until ad details page is scraped. but see the screenshot you can access the posting date of an ad in listing page.

Comment: thanks, but I should have been more specific: I need the hour and minute as well which is only displayed in the detailed view. I tried to omit these details in the original post to simplify.

Comment: but now that you say I think I can live with your solution as well. Thanks a lot for your help!